# NodeJS MongoDB Update $inc

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm not succeeding in updating my mongodb collection with the $inc operator.
I've created a test collection to simplify things.

My code:

```
collection.update({field1: 'text'}, { $inc: { items: 5 } }, function (error, result) {
    if (error) reject(error);
    else resolve(result);
});
```

My collection:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d2d56a931d867cfeeba4cb"),
    "field1" : "text",
    "items" : 0
}
```

The update operation returns no errors, response is OK with 0 updated documents.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. My mongodb library version is 2.0.39

[edit]
I've also tried updateOne method since I saw update is deprecated in version 2, same result though

Comment: What happens when you try running the equivalent update in mongo instead of node?

Comment: Wasn't familiar with explain(), and it seems its not yet available in the mongodb driver for nodejs. Running it in mongo directly proves fine, here is the update I ran:  db.getCollection('alex').update({"field1" : "text"},{$inc: { items: 5 }});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up realizing had unrelated connection to mongo issues, the above code actually works very well.

Comment: I suspected the same. I was a bit skeptical due to the lack of error message though.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this , as similar in my code.Hope this helps.

```
 collection.update({field1:'text'}, {$inc: {items: 5}}, function (err, product) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({error: 1, message: err, data: []});
                } else {
                    res.json({error: 0, message: 'success', data: {count_likes: product}});
                }
            });
```