# How can I add 1 to a value in a MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

When using `findOneAndUpdate` how can I add one to a value? In this case, I want to add 1 to the commandsUsed Object. Example Below:

```
await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
   try {
      await userSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
         _id: author.id,
      }, {
         _id: author.id,
         commandsUsed: //I want to add 1 to this Object
      }, {
         upsert: true,
  })
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065574/nodejs-mongodb-update-inc

Comment: Sort of, but I want it to get the current value then add 1 to it.

Comment: That's exactly what $inc does.

Comment: Are you able to give me an example?

Comment: Sure https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findOne` then add the field, finally save it.

```
const doc = await userSchema.findOne({ _id: author.id })
doc.commandsUsed++
doc.save();
```

Comment: this is not atomic, by the time i increase 1, somone else could have changed the value, and wrong results can happen, use update methods and `$inc` operator, to be atomic